# pysimplegui - Main Window Not Responding While Second Window is Open

Tags: windows, window, pysimplegui

When the window opens from the win() function, the key='hello' button does not do anything until the new window is closed. I can still click the button, but nothing happens until the window is closed.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def win():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Window')]]
    window = sg.Window('Database Table View', layout, size=(500,500))
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
    window.close()

def main():
    layout = [[sg.Button('Get Hello', key='hello')],
            [sg.Button('Get Window', key='window')],
            [sg.Text('', key='text')]]

    window = sg.Window('Test', layout, size=(1000,500))

    while True:
        event, values = window.Read(timeout=100)

        #How to close the window
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
            break

        if event == 'hello':
            window['text'].Update('Hello')
        elif event == 'window':
            window['text'].Update('')
            win()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Event loop in your main window is blocked at `win()`, so no response until it back to main window.

Comment: @JasonYang what can I do to to have the win() window active and still get a response from the main window?

Comment: Try function `sg.read_all_windows` for multi-windows.

Comment: @JasonYang could you provide an example? I'm not sure how I would change the code to incorporate `sg.read_all_windows`

Answer (score 0):

Foolwing code demo the way how main window and child window all work at the same time by function `sg.read_all_windows`.

```py
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def new_window(index):
    w, h = sg.Window.get_screen_size()
    location = (randint(500, w-500), randint(200, h-200))
    layout = [[sg.Text(f'This is sub-window {index}', key='TEXT')], [sg.Button('OK')]]
    return sg.Window(f'Window {index}', layout, location=location, no_titlebar=True, finalize=True)

layout = [[sg.Button('New Window')]]
main_window = sg.Window('Main Window', layout=layout, finalize=True)
windows = [main_window]
index = 0
while True:

    win, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'OK'):
        if win == main_window:
            break
        win.close()
        windows.remove(win)
        index -= 1
        for i, w in enumerate(windows[1:]):
            w['TEXT'].update(f'This is sub-window {i+1}')

    elif event == 'New Window':
        index += 1
        new_win = new_window(index)
        windows.append(new_win)
        main_window.force_focus()

for win in windows:
    win.close()
```